# Google sheet arrayformula doesn't work with (Index(query(filter)

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas

I would like to use the following formula in arrayformula so I do not need to pull down if new entries appear. Can you help please what am i missing? Thank you.

=Arrayformula(INDEX(Query(FILTER(B2:B, C2:C=I2:I), "select Col1 where Col1 is not null", false), 1, 1))

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=FILTER(B2:B, C2:C=I2:I, C2:C<>"")
```